# Faster permutation generator

Tags: list, optimization, scala, functional-programming, permutation

I've written a permutation generator for Scala lists that generates all permutations of a given list. So far, I've got the following based on [this Haskell implementation](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2006-July/018298.html) (and I think it's more efficient than several other options I've tried). Are there any ways to make this even more efficient, or have I covered all my bases?

```
   /** For each element x in List xss, returns (x, xss - x) */
   def selections[A](xss:List[A]):List[(A,List[A])] = xss match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case x :: xs =>
         (x, xs) :: (for( (y, ys) <- selections (xs) )
            yield (y, x :: ys))
   }

   /** Returns a list containing all permutations of the input list */
   def permute[A](xs:List[A]):List[List[A]] = xs match {
      case Nil => List(Nil)

      //special case lists of length 1 and 2 for better performance
      case t :: Nil => List(xs)
      case t :: u :: Nil => List(xs,List(u,t))

      case _ => 
         for ( (y,ys) <- selections(xs); ps <- permute(ys))
            yield y :: ps
   }
```

Comment: Is this faster than the array-based swap method?  Or do you mean "fastest functional permutation generator"?  (You never explicitly say so, but you added the tag....)

Comment: I do mean the fastest functional permutation generator. For that reason, haven't tried comparing this to the array-based swap method.

Comment: There are better algorithms. I saw one here on Stack Overflow not long ago, in Scala, which returned the next permutation (assuming a set of indices), instead of a list of all permutations. It used `partition` to find the point of the next index permutation, and generally avoided non-tail recursive calls. Also, of course, Haskell's implementation of the code you have shown would run very fast, because it wouldn't compute anything up-front. :-)

Comment: I should point out that my interest in this is mostly to elicit optimization tips if there are any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala 2.9 extempore have added some useful methods to scala collection class, include a Seq.permutations which generating all permutations of this seq. See [link text](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala). And I have a non-recursive implementation which I think would have a better performance. See [A non-recursive implementation of SeqLike.permutations](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4060)

Comment: Well, the version in Scala 2.9 svn right now seems to be similar to mine in its implemetation, only it runs out of memory trying to permute a 10 item list, and it has much worse performance than mine. Your version is slower than mine for short (5 item) lists, but faster for longer (10 item) lists. Plus, you use less memory at once, because you return an iterator.

Comment: For my use case, it would slow things down to try and eliminate duplicates, because there presumably are no duplicates, and `==` on my objects takes a long time (though the benchmarks I discuss here were performed with a List[Int]).

Comment: Yes, Extempore or my implementation is available to Seq with duplicates e.g. List(1,1,1,2,2,2)