# Scala permutation of Factorials

Tags: scala

How can I find the `n!` permutations of certain letters on Scala?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Faster permutation generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596724/faster-permutation-generator)

Comment: This a fundamental programming exercise, do it yourself!

Answer (score 9):

Scala 2.9 RC1:

```
scala> "abc".permutations.toList
res58: List[String] = List(abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba)
```

Comment: I would like to note, that the number of permutations may quickly become very large. If you make call `permutations.toList` doesn't it create all of those probably many permuations and stores all of them in memory at once. If that is correct the java process may quickly get out of memory. `permutations` returns an `Iterator` which does not have this problem, because it creates the permutations lazily, one after the other. You can e.g. use the map or collect functions to process the permutations the same way.

Answer (score 8):

```
scala> def permutations[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
     |     case Nil => List(Nil)
     |     case _   => for(x <- xs;ys <- permutations(xs diff List(x))) yield x::ys
     | }
permutations: [T](xs: List[T])List[List[T]]

scala> permutations("abc".toList) foreach println
List(a, b, c)
List(a, c, b)
List(b, a, c)
List(b, c, a)
List(c, a, b)
List(c, b, a)
```