# Scala permutation of Factorials

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala permutation of Factorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056669/scala-permutation-of-factorials)

My problem is that I have to take a result permutation on Factorial.
**Question:** Print out all n! permutations of the n letters starting at a (26 letters). A permutation of n elements is one of the n! possible orderings of the elements. AS an example, when n = 3 you should get the following output. For Example: abc bac acb cab cba bca

Answer (score 4):

In scala 2.9, there is a method called permutations of Seq.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.r24073-b20110124174250 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_18).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> "abc".permutations foreach println
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba

scala> "abcd".permutations foreach println
abcd
abdc
acbd
acdb
adbc
adcb
bacd
badc
bcad
bcda
bdac
bdca
cabd
cadb
cbad
cbda
cdab
cdba
dabc
dacb
dbac
dbca
dcab
dcba

scala>
```

Or just implement it yourself:

```
scala> def permutations[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
     |     case Nil => List(Nil)
     |     case _   => for(x <- xs;ys <- permutations(xs diff List(x))) yield x::ys
     | }
permutations: [T](xs: List[T])List[List[T]]

scala> permutations("abc".toList) foreach println
List(a, b, c)
List(a, c, b)
List(b, a, c)
List(b, c, a)
List(c, a, b)
List(c, b, a)
```

Comment: How about if there are just letters for example 26 letters abcdefghi...... Then user will input the number for example: if you put and print 5. It will choose first 5 letters and print permutation.

Comment: Is this your homework? I have gave the code already, do it yourself the rest.

Comment: It would be interesting to add this answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056669/scala-permutation-of-factorials.

Comment: Thank you Eastsun. It is not homework I am learning Scala. New Learner.