# how to write a function that prints all the possible strings from a given string?

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a code that does the following:
 1. there is a string "abc"
 2.it prints all the possible strings from it: abc, bac, cba, acb, cab, bca

The following is the code I wrote, however it gives an error all the time:

```
def swap(n: Int, source: String): String = {
  val new_array = source.toCharArray
  if (n == 1) {
    new_string
  } else {
    var letter = new_array(n)
    letter = new_array(n-1)
    new_array(n-1) = letter
    var k = new String(new_array)
    swap(n, source)
  }
}
```

Can you please tell me where is my mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: I think it would benefit you to do more yourself before asking questions here. You've asked a whole pile here today - you'd get more learning from trying yourself first...

Comment: The word you are looking for is "permutation", sam.

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> "abc".permutations.toList
res1: List[String] = List(abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba)
```

I wouldn't turn that one in though.

Comment: Works only on Scala 2.9 (which is not an officially released version at this moment).

Answer (score 2):

The **really obvious** mistake is you have your names all mixed up.

I can see `new_array` being initialised, but then you try to use `new_string`, which doesn't seem to be coming from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious thing is that you try to swap two letters, but you got the order wrong. It should be

```
val letter = new_array(n)
new_array(n) = new_array(n-1)
new_array(n-1) = letter
```

There might be other errors, but as this is homework...

Comment: Can you please tell me where the error is? Is it in the recalling the swap function? Can you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: they "but as this is homework..." comment means you need to figure this out for yourself, as it is homework, work **you** should do at home.

Comment: I already showed you one error. Another one is that you call swap with exactly the the same arguments as you got - which always leads to an infinite loop. Usually something gets smaller, simpler, shorter in a recursive call (until you hit the final "edge case").

Answer (score 0):

As said before, it's a permutation problem. With Scala 2.8, you could write something like that :

```
def permut[T](l: List[T]): List[List[T]] = {
  def retire(e: T, l: List[T]): List[T] = l match {
    case Nil                => Nil
    case x::xs if e == x    => xs
    case x::xs              => x::retire(e, xs)
  }

  l match {
    case Nil => List(Nil)
    case _   => for ( x <- l; p <- permut(retire(x, l))) yield (x :: p)
  }
}
```

Then :

```
scala> permut("abc" toList) map {_.mkString }                              
res11: List[String] = List(abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba)
```

(I'm not sure my permutation is optimal, though. At least, retire could be tail recursive'd)

Comment: Oops... Seems i've reinvented the diff method :)

Comment: I think your `retire` is suboptimal. See my [Scala version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596724/faster-permutation-generator), and the [Haskell discussion](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2006-July/018298.html) it's based on.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a `next_permutation` function, whose operation can be summed up as follows: look for the longest suffix of the array that is in descending order -- let's say it starts at index m. Figure out where the value at index m-1 belongs in that suffix, and swap the two values. Then reverse the suffix from m to the end of the list so that it is in sorted order.